# Transitive sets: problem in proof of Lemma I.8.6 of Kunen's 'Foundations of Mathematics'

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I've been studying Kunen's notes titled '[The Foundations of Mathematics](https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m771-10/kunen770.pdf)'.

Definition I.8.1 in Kunen says

> $z$ is a transitive set iff $\forall y \in z\, [y \subseteq z]$

In the proof of Lemma I.8.6, $\alpha$ is a transitive set and $x,y,z \in \alpha$. Kunen claims that

> … we have $x \in y \in z \rightarrow x \in z$ because the $\in$
>   relation is transitive on $\alpha$ …

But this does not seem to follow from Kunen's definiton of transitivity. Consider $\alpha=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$. Then it is transitive by Kunen's definition but if we take $x$, $y$ and $z$ to be the three elements in the order given then $x \in y \in z$ but $x \notin z$.

Am I reasoning correctly?

I also have the print edition of the notes and the definition and proof are identical there.

Comment: I think the source of the confusion may be that for ordinals like $\alpha$, two non-equivalent statements are true, both specified, *explicitly and independently*, in Kunen's definition of ordinals.  These are (1) $\alpha$ is a *transitive set*; and (2) $\alpha$ is *well-ordered* by $\in$.  The inference you cited follows not from (1), as your question implies, but from (2) (since well-orderedness implies total strict orderedness, which in turn implies the transitivity of the order relation, which in this case happens to be $\in$).

Comment: (continued) In other words, your phrase "Kunen's definition of transitivity" is ambiguous, since it can refer either to the the definition of a *transitive* ***relation*** (first item in **Definition I.7.2**, p. 24) or to the definition of a *transitive* ***set*** (**Definition I.8.1**, p. 33).  In your post's second excerpt, Kunen is explicitly invoking the former, which applies because $\in$ well-orders $\alpha$, not because $\alpha$, as a set, is transitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption is that $\alpha$ is not *any* transitive set, but an ordinal. Which is a transitive set that is *well-ordered* by $\in$. In particular $\in$ is a transitive relation on $\alpha$ in the usual sense.

You are correct that this reasoning need not apply to arbitrary transitive sets, though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that the end of the proof of Lemma I.8.6 in Kunen is misleading and incomplete.  It can be fixed as below.

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal, that is, $\alpha$ is a transitive set (every element of it is a subset of it) such that the relation $\in$ on $\alpha$ is a well-order (i.e., a (strict) total order for which every nonempty subset has a minimal element).

At the end of the proof of I.8.6 we have $x\in y\in z\in\alpha$ with $x,y,z\in\alpha$.  We have to show that $x\in z$. Because $\in$ is a total order, we either have (1) $z=x$, or (2) $z\in x$, or (3) $x\in z$.  Case (1) is impossible because that would give a cycle $x\in y\in x$ with no minimal element for the set $\{x,y\}$.  Case (2) is impossible because that would give a cycle $x\in y\in z\in x$ with no minimal element for the set $\{x,y,z\}$.  So case (3) $x\in z$ must hold.

Your example $A=\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ is a transitive set, but the $\in$ relation on $A$ is not a well-order, as it is not even a total order: the elements $\emptyset$ and $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ are not comparable, as neither is a member of the other.  As you correctly observed, $A$ being a *transitive set* is not enough to conclude that the relation $\in$ on $A$ is a *transitive relation*.